# save object Id from one table to another table

Tags: string, parse-platform, type-conversion

I am getting ObjectId from one table and want to save another table which has column field name 'owner' with datatype 'Pointer<_User>'. But when I tried to do this I got this error 'invalid type for key owner, expected *_User, but got string'.
Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: I hope my answer was helpful to you.  Its customary to mark correct (or up-vote) answer that are correct or helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the title of the question.  The operand to a pointer column isn't an object id, it is an object.

So if you have an object, say a PFUser, do this:

```
// user is a PFUser
myObjectThatPointsToUser("owner", user);
```

If you have only a user's object id as a string, ask yourself why. To the extent you can, design to converse in objects, not ids.  But if you find yourself in this situation, set the pointer column like this:

```
// userId is the id of a PFUser
var userStub = { "__type": "Pointer",
                 "className": "_User",
                 "objectId": userId };

myObjectThatPointsToUser("owner", userStub);
```